# Handle nan values in rolling operations

Tags: python-polars

I'm testing rolling operation and I have the following problem:

```
import polars as pl
import numpy as np

df = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "values": [np.nan, 1, 1, 2, 4, 5, 3]
    }
)

df = df.select(
    [
        pl.all(),
        pl.col("values").rolling_apply(lambda s: s.min(), window_size=2).alias("rolling rank"),
        pl.col("values").rolling_min(window_size=2).alias("rolling min native")
    ]
)

print(df)
```

This code doesn't work but if I remove np.nan it works perfectly. Is there a bug in rolling operations?

```
File "/usr/local/anaconda3/envs/learn_polars/lib/python3.10/site-packages/polars/internals/lazy_frame.py", line 476, in collect
    return self._dataframe_class._from_pydf(ldf.collect())
pyo3_runtime.PanicException: called `Option::unwrap()` on a `None` value
```

In addiction, this works:

```
df = df.select(
    [
        pl.all(),
        pl.col("values").rolling_apply(lambda s: s.min(), window_size=2).alias("rolling rank"),
    ]
)
```

I also tried min_period but nothing changed.

Polars version, provided by pip: 0.13.16

Thanks

Comment: This indeed look like a bug.  I've submitted a bug report on GitHub.  https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/3099.

Answer (score 1):

This issue is now fixed in Polars `0.13.21`.  If you update you should be able to take advantage of the better performance of the function-specific `rolling_` methods (e.g., `rolling_min`, `rolling_quantile`, etc..)

```py
df.with_columns(
    [
        pl.col("values").rolling_apply(lambda s: s.min(), window_size=2).alias("rolling min"),
        pl.col("values").rolling_min(window_size=2).alias("rolling min native")
    ]
)
```

```
shape: (7, 3)
┌────────┬─────────────┬────────────────────┐
│ values ┆ rolling min ┆ rolling min native │
│ ---    ┆ ---         ┆ ---                │
│ f64    ┆ f64         ┆ f64                │
╞════════╪═════════════╪════════════════════╡
│ NaN    ┆ null        ┆ null               │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 1.0    ┆ 1.0         ┆ NaN                │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 1.0    ┆ 1.0         ┆ 1.0                │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2.0    ┆ 1.0         ┆ 1.0                │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 4.0    ┆ 2.0         ┆ 2.0                │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 5.0    ┆ 4.0         ┆ 4.0                │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 3.0    ┆ 3.0         ┆ 3.0                │
└────────┴─────────────┴────────────────────┘
```

Note that the optimized, function-specific `rolling_` methods may treat NaN values differently than a generic `rolling_apply`.